# What is the name of the tool that can be used to replace tokens with strings?

Tags: json, prototyping

Sorry for the vague question, but I'm looking for the name of a tool (which I know exists) that lets you put tokens in your HTML and then the server replaces those tokens with strings stored in a simple text file?

I think it is based on JSON format.

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: Well, that's called variables no? :P

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

Edit: [Smarty?](http://www.smarty.net/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for.  It is a utility that you can install on your server that replaces tokens in HTML with strings. It is very useful for prototyping interfaces, so you can test the layout against different strings.